# OpenFaces tutorials

Tags: java, treetable

Are there any places online where you can find tutorials for the openfaces components? I have been trying to implement a dynamic tree table for a few days and I am having trouble, but the documentation isn't helpful at all so it makes it tough to overcome this obstacle.

Thanks,

Quinton

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [documentation](http://openfaces.org/documentation/) and [FAQ](https://sites.google.com/a/teamdev.com/openfaces-support/documentation/openfaces-faq), you may find these articles useful:

- [An Introduction to OpenFaces, Part 1](http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/openfaces_1.html) -- General overview;
- [An Introduction to OpenFaces, Part 2](http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/openfaces_2.html) -- DataTable and TreeTable components overview.

You can also [download](http://openfaces.org/downloads/) the source code for the OpenFaces demo application to study the working examples.

If the documentation is not clear enough, you can search for a solution or ask for a clarification on the discussion [forum](http://links.teamdev.com/openfaces-forum).